# When updating my app Android crashes completely

Tags: android, crash

I have no glue what is going wrong with my old/new version of my app. When updating existing apk with newer one (new version), the whole system crashes and reboots. Reproducable with Nexus One (CM7 Android 2.3.3) and Galaxy S (2.3.3). This is part of my log:

```
     5-28 13:52:20.587 I/ActivityManager(  162): Start proc com.android.packageinstaller for activity com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: pid=10478 uid=10046 gids={}
    05-28 13:52:21.258 I/ActivityManager(  162): No longer want com.android.defcontainer (pid 10249): hidden #16
    05-28 13:52:25.112 I/ActivityManager(  162): Starting: Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/download/lw_free-2.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) } from pid 10478
    05-28 13:52:25.192 I/ActivityManager(  162): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=10488 uid=10030 gids={1015, 2001}
    05-28 13:52:25.412 W/ActivityManager(  162): No content provider found for: 
    05-28 13:52:25.712 W/ActivityManager(  162): No content provider found for: 
    05-28 13:52:25.822 I/ActivityManager(  162): Force stopping package de.dd.lw.free uid=10088
    05-28 13:52:25.822 W/ActivityManager(  162): Scheduling restart of crashed service de.dd.lw.free/.LiveWallpaper in 5000ms
    05-28 13:52:25.822 I/ActivityManager(  162):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{40cdd920 de.dd.lw.free/.LiveWallpaper}
    05-28 13:52:25.832 W/WallpaperService(  162): Wallpaper service gone: ComponentInfo{de.dd.lw.free/de.dd.lw.free.LiveWallpaper}
    05-28 13:52:25.832 I/WindowManager(  162): WIN DEATH: Window{40c22560 de.dd.lw.free.LiveWallpaper paused=false}
    05-28 13:52:26.143 I/PackageManager(  162): Package de.dd.lw.free codePath changed from /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-1.apk to /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
    05-28 13:52:26.143 I/PackageManager(  162): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-2.apk
    05-28 13:52:26.383 I/ActivityManager(  162): Force stopping package de.dd.lw.free uid=10088
    05-28 13:52:26.393 W/PackageManager(  162): Code path for pkg : de.dd.lw.free changing from /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-1.apk to /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-2.apk
    05-28 13:52:26.393 W/PackageManager(  162): Resource path for pkg : de.dd.lw.free changing from /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-1.apk to /data/app/de.dd.lw.free-2.apk
    05-28 13:52:26.783 I/ActivityManager(  162): Force stopping package de.dd.lw.free uid=10088
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:de.dd.lw.free flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in com.android.server.WallpaperManagerService$MyPackageMonitor@4094bf08
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:584)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown component ComponentInfo{de.dd.lw.free/de.dd.lw.free.LiveWallpaper}
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at com.android.server.WallpaperManagerService.bindWallpaperComponentLocked(WallpaperManagerService.java:570)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at com.android.server.WallpaperManagerService$MyPackageMonitor.onPackageUpdateFinished(WallpaperManagerService.java:225)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.onReceive(PackageMonitor.java:210)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
    05-28 13:52:27.174 E/AndroidRuntime(  162):     ... 4 more
    05-28 13:52:27.214 I/ActivityThread(10488): Removing dead content provider: settings
    05-28 13:52:27.224 I/ActivityThread( 8817): Removing dead content provider: settings
    05-28 13:52:27.234 I/ActivityThread( 7213): Removing dead content provider: settings
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-25
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ContextImpl.java:1747)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at com.tmobile.thememanager.provider.ThemesProvider$3.handlePackageEvent(ThemesProvider.java:633)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at com.tmobile.thememanager.provider.ThemesProvider$3.access$400(ThemesProvider.java:604)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at com.tmobile.thememanager.provider.ThemesProvider$3$1.run(ThemesProvider.java:612)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInfo(IPackageManager.java:1075)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ContextImpl.java:1742)
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 9307):     ... 3 more
    05-28 13:52:27.244 E/AndroidRuntime( 8125): FATAL EXCEPTION: carhome-loader
```

Comment: Are you using custom ROM on your phones? Like Cyanogenmod?

Comment: "Yes" on the Nexus One. "No" on the Samsung Galaxy S.

Answer (score 2):

You have a live wallpaper configured on the device, attached to a `de.dd.lw.free.LiveWallpaper` component. It would appear that this component does not exist in your new version.

Comment: This live wallpaper is my app which I would like to update. I have no glue how Android uninstalls the old version and then fails to install the new one. If I manually remove the old one no problem at all.

Comment: @dedeep: Did you change the service class name of the live wallpaper between the old and new version?

Comment: Ohh thanks for directing me into correct direction. I forgot already. I refactored the free and paid version to have the same codebase (in a new library project). So in the free version (in the log above) the service class moved to a different package.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Do you know some workarounds? I am currently thinking of duplicating the class for one version... Maybe I could derive from the new class and put an extend'ed version into the old package?

Comment: @dedeep: In theory, you could have your free app subclass the library project's service, so you can get the old package. I have not implemented a live wallpaper and so I do not know if that would somehow introduce any particular problems. It is at least worth a shot, I would think.

Comment: Ok this really works if I am using old names in Manifest. Thanks!